# Proofing whether a subset of \mathbb{R^2}$ is a sub vector space or not

Tags: vector-spaces

Given is the set $$U = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | x^2 + 4xy +4y^2 = 0\} = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | y = -\frac{x}{2}\}$$

In order for the set to be a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ three conditions have to be true:

1. $u, v \in U: u + v \in U$
2. $u \in U: s * u \in U,  \forall s \in \mathbb{K}$
3. $0\in U$

For condition 1, I can show that the vectors $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are linearly dependent by changing either $x$ or $y$ for the respective equivalent according to the equation and showing that there are non-trivial solutions for $(x_1, y_1) + (x_2 + y_2) = 0$, which means that $(x_1, y_1) + (x_2 + y_2)$ ist just a vector $(x_3, y_3)$ that is indeed $\in U$. Please correct me if my reasoning is wrong here.

Now, the actual question is related to condition 2. How do I prove that $s*u\in U$? Can I just reason with the linear dependence again? If not, how do I prove it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y_1 = -x_1/2$ and $y_2 = -x_2/2$ then $y_1 + y_2 = -(x_1 + x_2)/2$.  This shows condition (1) is satisfied.  It has nothing to do with  $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ being linearly dependent.  Similarly, condition (2) is satisfied because if $y = -x/2$ then $sy = -(sx)/2$.

Comment: But by doing this you are only showing that the operations can be done, not that the results are in the set. What am I missing?

Comment: I am showing that if $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are in the set, then their sum $(x_1+x_2, y_1 + y_2)$ is in the set.  That's exactly what you need for (1).  Similarly, I am showing that if $(x,y)$ is in the set, then $s(x,y)$ is in the set, which is what you need for (2).